# Nested data in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4

I download several entities one ajax-request. Then i add them to stores. I need to commit a changes alike one ajax-request. How properly to do it?

Json structure:

```
{
    entity1: [],
    entity2: [],
    entyty3: []
}


success: function(responce) {
    var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
    store1.add(data['entity1']);
    store2.add(data['entity2']);
    store3.add(data['entity3']);
}
```

Comment: store type is not clear here. is It JsonStore?

Comment: suggest to describe issue with more details. like how your are submitting, stores definition etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can send it as JSON and that can easily be done as follows:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'YourURL',
    jsonData: YourObjectRef, // can be any object / array or JSON string
    success: function(response, opts) {
        // your code
    }
});
```

And if you want to do it with a store use the type `auto` for the Modelfield. This type can contain any object.

Check the following references:

[ExtJs 4.0.7 Stores](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)

[ExtJs 3.4.0 Stores](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore)

Kindly check `autoSync` property to automatically sync the Store with its Proxy after every edit to one of its Records. Defaults to false.

Comment: I need to send only changed records. And what to do if server will assign id added record and return a changes?

Answer (score 0):

you may use like this. because in extjs4, it's necessary to use the model to create a record

```
success: function(responce) {
  var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText),record;
  Ext.each(data,function(entity,index,dataItself){
      record = Ext.create('YOURMODEL',entity);
      store.add(record);   
  });
}
```